# Dashcode Widgets Datasource

Tags: dashcode

I would like to know if there is a Reference manual somewhere for Dashcode 3.0 Widgets' datasources.

I need to know the following:

1. How to refresh (requery) a datasource
2. How to listen for datasource events (onsuccess, onerror)
3. How to pass parameter to datasource query

It's being very difficult for me to find this very basic information in Apple's documentation.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I need to know about #2 - I want to trigger my own function when the datasource is updated.  At the moment I'm having to use setTimeout() and poll for the presence of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer #3, to pass a parameter to the datasource query:

```
ds = dashcode.getDataSource("mydatasource");
ds.setValueForKeyPath("1", "parameters.count");
ds.setValueForKeyPath("bar", "parameters.foo");
```

will add `?count=1&foo=bar` to the query URL.

For #1, an answer I saw whilst searching this topic was to add an additional parameter which you change for each query to trigger a requery:

```
ds.setValueForKeyPath(update++, "parameters.update");
```

I still need to know the answer to #2 myself.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/PartsReference/PartsReference.html) is not the most complete guid but it does do over reloading datasources.